# react naviagation deep link didnt work on older chrome react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I developed a react native application and use react navigation for routing and deep links.deep link test with `npx uri-scheme` and every thin is ok.
in real device(android) deep linking didn't work in older version of chrome (v103 and down) and versions upper than 103 every thing is ok. can anyone help me to solve my problem?
I tested in every version of android and result is same

here is my config of linking in react-navigation :

```
  const linking = {
prefixes: ['app://newApp'],
config: {
  screens: {
    MainRoutes: {
      screens: {
        drawer: {
          screens: {
            ContactUs: 'contactus',
          },
        },
        SuccessFallBack: {
          path: 'paymentsuccess/:resNum?',
        },
        FailFallback: {
          path: 'paymentfail/:resNum?',
        },

      },
    },
  },
},
```

and here is my intent filter:

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="newApp"  />
    <data android:scheme="app" />
    </intent-filter>
```

and package versions :

```
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
     "react-native": "0.71.11",
```